# PIG logical, filter, group, nested FOREACH, unknown error

Tags: foreach, apache-pig

Good day, hi all, if you have a moment to spare, do you mind helping me to look for the error?

The error is ERROR 1200: @ gruu_500 = GROUP* prio_500 all, where * indicates the exact line and column of the error.

It says that there's a syntax error, unexcpected symbol at or near 'prio_500'

```
DESCRIBE data_
data_:{a: chararray, b: int, c:int, d: int, e: int, f: int, g: int, h: int, i: int
 ,j: int, k: chararray, l: chararray, m: chararray, n: chararray, o: chararray}

data_500 = FILTER data_ BY ($8 == 500);
grop_500 = GROUP data_500 ALL;

bich_500 = FOREACH grop_500{
prio_500 = FILTER data_ BY (e <= data_500.e) AND (a MATCHES data_500.a);
gruu_500 = GROUP prio_500 ALL;
GENERATE gruu_500;}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `prio_500 = FILTER data_`...  be `prio_500 = FILTER data_500`... because you are doing the `GROUP ALL` on data_500?  I dunno if this will fix your syntax error though.

Comment: Actually i am trying to compare two different lists. Say for all entries in List_A.col_A > an entry in List_B.col_A then i will store all those entries into a single tuple. So i will have number of entries in List_B amount of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the top voted answer in

[Can I generate nested bags using nested FOREACH statements in Pig Latin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932673/can-i-generate-nested-bags-using-nested-foreach-statements-in-pig-latin)

Thanks for your time!